# Form validation with more than one files and other input fields together

Tags: javascript, php, forms, validation

I have a form that allows the user to input text and upload at least one file, with file size less than 1GB. When clicking "Submit" button of the form, this requirement will be validated by javascript. However, when I add the validation for files, it does not have any response for showing the name and size of the files, especially if the file exceeds 1GB.

Which one of the following approaches would be better?

1. Check the file size after selecting the file, if the file size exceeds 1GB, there will be an alert telling the user that the file is too large and need to choose again.
2. After choosing file(s), when clicking "submit" button, before proceeding to PHP for uploading file(s) to the server, the validation of the whole form, including input text field and file size, is done with JavaScript.

Here's my form:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="validate.js"></script>
  <form id="fileUpload" method="post" action="upload_action.php">
    <p>Text input: <input type="text" name="text_input" value=""/></p>
    <p>File upload: <input type="file" name="upload_file[]" multiple/></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return validate_form();"/>
  </form>
```

And my validation JavaScript (`validate.js`):

```
function validate_form() {
    var valid=true;
    if (document.forms['fileUpload']['text_input'].value=='') {
        alert('You have to enter text');
        valid=false;
    }

    // File size validation goes here
}
```

EDIT at 12:20pm Hong Kong Time:

Now the check of the files' sizes can be done as follows:

In PHP file:

```
<form id="fileUpload" method="post" action="upload_action.php">
    <p>Text input: <input type="text" name="text_input" value=""/></p>
    <p>File upload: <input type="file" id="upload_file" name="upload_file[]" multiple="true"></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return validate_form();"/>
  </form>
```

In javascript

```
var MAX_SIZE = 1073741824;
    var x=document.getElementById("upload_file");  
    for(var i=0; i<x.files.length; i++)
    {
         if (x.files[i].size > MAX_SIZE) {
            alert('The file "'+x.files[i].name+'" has exceeded the max file size, 1GB. Please choose smaller file.');
            valid=false;
            return false; 
         }
    }
```

But then I have to face another problem: when I selected the files from file dialog, I just saw the word "2 files" near the "choose" button, instead of the names of selected files. So what can I do so that the selected files' names can be shown? Thanks again!

Comment: You can validate on client side, but that is not so secure, so you SHOULD always validate on server side too!

Comment: document.forms['fileUpload'] U should be capital

Comment: Thanks for @ShoaibChikate's notice, I've changed it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

man. I vote after the file input is changed, so the user has a chance to correct immediately.

If I understand you correctly, you could do something like this in a change event:

```
var MAX = 1000000000;
if (document.forms['fileUpload']['text_input'].files[0].size > MAX) {
    valid = false;
    alert('you have exceeded the max file size, 1GB. Please choose smaller file.');
    return false; // no submit
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: document.forms['fileupload'] will be undefined as id is case sensitive

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Your method is similar to be successful, but finally I changed to use id to let the javascript to get the file elements.

Answer (score 1):

As your file select is of multiple type, you need to iterate files array and check the size of each file

```
function validate_form(){

var MAX_SIZE = 1000000000;
var myForm=document.forms['fileUpload']

//other field validations   

for(var file in myForm['upload_file[]'].files)
     if (file.size > MAX) {
        alert('you have exceeded the max file size, 1GB. Please choose smaller file.');
        return false; 
     }
}


}
```

Comment: good catch! I didn't notice the multiple prop. Presumably, though... the OP knows how(-ish?) to check the file size by now, though the question of when the validation should occur still remains. I vote in an change event handler for the file input. Your thoughts?

Comment: OP is not responding. He can call validation method onsubmit or onchange event whatever he wish.